# Matlab bug when using nchoosek function in batch processing

Tags: matlab, batch-processing

I have a simple program which sorts the rows and columns of data using the result of the `nchoosek` function. The program will sort haversinetest data (4x4) and return the values of `setdiffansall` and `sortdataall`. Below are the details:

```
Haversinetest = 

0                   4.28000000000000    40.0900000000000    28.3000000000000
4.28000000000000    0                   39.0300000000000    26.8200000000000
40.0900000000000    39.0300000000000    0                   64.1400000000000
28.2600000000000    26.8200000000000    64.1400000000000    0
```

Below is the program

```
[x1,y1] = size(haversinetest);
x1 = 1:1:x1;
removeSelection = y1;
setdiffansall = {};
sortdataall = {};

for f=0:1:y1
    groupsOfData = x1(nchoosek(x1,numel(x1)-f));
    [x2,y2] = size(groupsOfData);
    for c=1:1:x2
        matrix1 = haversinetest;
        rows2remove = [groupsOfData(c,:)];
        cols2remove = [groupsOfData(c,:)];
        matrix1(rows2remove,:) = [];
        matrix1(:,cols2remove) = [];
        sortdata = matrix1;

        setdiffans = setdiff(x1,cols2remove);
        setdiffansall = [setdiffansall;setdiffans];
        sortdataall = [sortdataall;sortdata];

    end
    removeSelection = removeSelection -1;
end
```

It should return `setdiffansall <15x1 cell>` but instead it just returned `<11x1 cell>` and skipped `nchoosek(data,3)`. If i run manually `groupsOfData = x1(nchoosek(x1,3));` it will generate the missing matrix.

I am using Matlab R2012b 32 bit version on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `removeSelection` variable? You only set it and change it, never actually use it.

Comment: Actually the programming attached is part of the big programming. Sorry I forgot to remove that variable which is not been using here.